# Why is my popover shifting my page? when i click it, it is making my page wider that I want

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, popover

So i have a user id popover on my page, when I click it, it shofts the page to make it wider, instead of moving itself within the boundariesof the page.

this is what it does
[image]

Notice that little white space, I dont want it to be there. When it is not clicked, it is normal
[image]

How do i format this properly?

Here is the popover component

```
import * as React from "react";
import Popover from "@mui/material/Popover";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import AccountCircleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle";
import { IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import navStyles from "../styles/Nav.module.css";
export default function BasicPopover() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton
        aria-describedby={id}
        variant="contained"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <AccountCircleIcon className={navStyles.pfp} />
      </IconButton>
      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left",
        }}
      >
        <Typography sx={{ p: 0, m: 0 }}>
          <ul>
            <li>Login/Logout</li>
            <li>Account</li>
            <li>Your Trips</li>
            <li>Help</li>
            <li>Settings</li>
          </ul>
        </Typography>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my nav component

```
import Link from "next/link";
import navStyles from "../styles/Nav.module.css";
import AccountMenu from "../components/AccountMenu.js";
import { useAuth } from "./contexts/userContext";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Nav = () => {
  const { logout, user } = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();

  async function handleLogout() {
    try {
      await logout();
      console.log("logged out");
      router.push("/");
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }

  return (
    <nav className={navStyles.nav}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link href="/">
            <img
              className={navStyles.logo}
              src="/blue.png"
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            />
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/Properties">Properties</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul style={{ margin: "0px", padding: "0px" }}>
        {!user ? (
          <li style={{ margin: "0px", padding: "0px" }}>
            <Link href="/Authentication/Login">Login </Link>
          </li>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <div style={{ color: "green" }}>Welcome {user?.email} </div>
            <li>
              <Link href="/Account">Account</Link>
            </li>
            <div
              onClick={handleLogout}
              style={{ color: "black", cursor: "pointer" }}
            >
              Logout
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        <li style={{ margin: "0px" }}>
          <AccountMenu className={navStyles.pfp} />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/ivan-irvine-97/pen/jOpMVOy

Hope I help!

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.username_left')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown button {
     background: url('https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/202-2024580_png-file-profile-icon-vector-png.png') no-repeat;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
  background-size: contain;
        border: none;
}
.dropdown {
position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
}
/* Dropdown Button */
.username_left {
  color: black;
  /* padding: 16px; */
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.username_left:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: none;
  color: #ffcfcf;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  /* position: relative; */
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  background: #fffffff2;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 right: 0%;
min-height: auto;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {


  color: indianred;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
.container {
float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
<div class="dropdown"> <button onclick="myFunction()" class="username_left">
 
</button>

<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="' . $v_user . '">My Profile</a>
    <a href="#">Switch Account</a>
    <a href="logout">Sign out</a>
  </div></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```